# How a trained DRL model run with smaller number of state?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I trained a DRL model with a large number of states, for example, my state dimension includes 1 hunter and 20 prey. But if I want to run my trained DRL model with less state dimension, let say, 1 hunter and 2 prey. How could my DRL model handle with variable state dimension?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. You added very little information about your problem. Consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions.

Comment: Maybe you could pad them with zeros. You might need to give some more information regarding the problem.

Comment: @nsidn98 Thank you very much. My DRL model is trained with the state dimension is N (predefined), but could I run the pre-trained model with a state dimension less than N (real state dimension)?

Comment: If the definition of the state is changing then you might have to train it again.

Comment: @nsidn98: Should I just pad the extra state with zeros?

Comment: Yes, you should maybe train the agent with a variety of state dimensions (all possible ones which you think it might encounter). So you can set your state dimension to be the maximum possible one and then for any state with a smaller state dimension, you can pad them with zeros.